# Strings from database are not shown correctly

Tags: phpmyadmin

I created a table in database named (wp_answers) to get the Persian sentences. so I use `get_charset_collate`. Now the strings in database saved correctly. But when i want to fetch these strings, they are not shown correctly. for example: سلام -> Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…
How can i correct this issue?
This is a part of my code for creating answers table and fetching the strings from this table.
thanks,

```
global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $answers_table = $wpdb->prefix. 'answers';
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$answers_table}'" ) != $answers_table ){
        $query =
            "CREATE TABLE {$answers_table} (
            poll_id BIGINT(20),
            ans_id BIGINT(20),
            ans_title VARCHAR(32),
            votes BIGINT(20),
            PRIMARY KEY (poll_id,ans_id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        require_once( ABSPATH. 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $query );
    }
```

-fetch:

```
<?php
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ans_title,votes
                                FROM wp_answers
                                WHERE poll_id=$post_id AND ans_id=$answer_id");
?>
  <h2><?php echo $result[0]->ans_title; ?><h2> //This would show Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… instead of سلام
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are your content type is utf-8 like header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
otherwise you can check example from this link. https://ideone.com/MC0hou